# Tcl error in 'if' branching

Tags: tcl

I am getting an error:

```
    invalid command name "tcl::mathfunc::expr"
```

while trying the following if code branching. The value of $env(EXB_DESIGN_NAME) is set to "seville2". I want the code should not branch in to the 'if' condition.

```
    if {expr("$env(EXB_DESIGN_NAME)" ne "seville") || expr("$env(EXB_DESIGN_NAME)" ne "seville2")} { -------}
```

Comment: BTW, at least one of those `ne` relations will always be true, which leads to the whole `if` expression always being true.

Comment: That's correct Peter, I have changed the logical OR to logical AND. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you should be writing it (quotes are optional here too for the variable):

```
if {"$env(EXB_DESIGN_NAME)" ne "seville" || "$env(EXB_DESIGN_NAME)" ne "seville2"} {
  #Do something
}
```

If you absolutely want to use `expr` though (not quite necessary here because `if` uses `expr`), it would be something like that:

```
if {[expr {"$env(EXB_DESIGN_NAME)" ne "seville"}] || [expr {"$env(EXB_DESIGN_NAME)" ne "seville2"}]} {
  #Do something
}
```

or

```
if {[expr {"$env(EXB_DESIGN_NAME)" ne "seville" || "$env(EXB_DESIGN_NAME)" ne "seville2"}]} {
  #Do something
}
```

But I wouldn't recommend writing the code like these since `if` since it is much simpler to write it in the first way I mentioned.

If you have a lot of strings to check, you might use [`ni`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/17963) (for 'not in'):

```
set mylist {"seville" "seville2"}
if {$env(EXB_DESIGN_NAME) ni $mylist} {
  #Do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tcl translates functions in expressions into calls to the equivalent command in the `tcl::mathfunc` namespace.

However, your real problem is that you are using `expr` as a function inside a context which is already an expression! You don't need that sort of complexity. This means we can change:

```
if {expr("$env(EXB_DESIGN_NAME)" ne "seville") || expr("$env(EXB_DESIGN_NAME)" ne "seville2")} { -------}
```

into:

```
if {$env(EXB_DESIGN_NAME) ne "seville" || $env(EXB_DESIGN_NAME) ne "seville2"} { -------}
```

It's shorter. It's clearer. It's correct…

Comment: `interp alias {} ::tcl::mathfunc::expr {} return -code ok` could also fix that problem. But I think that's a bad idea.